# Query with hierarchical structure and variable number of hierarchy levels

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy

I have table 'Areas' containing customer's areas:

```
ID, AREA_NAME, PARENT_ID
```

Areas are organized in hierarchy up to four levels using PARENT_ID pointing to parent's AREA_ID. PARENT_ID for top level Area IS NULL.

Table of 'Customers' hase AREA_ID referencing the lowest level of area hierarchy:

```
ID, CUSTOMER_NAME, AREA_ID
```

I want to get the result table like this:

```
CUSTOMER_NAME,AREA_LVL_1,AREA_LVL_2,AREA_LVL_3,AREA_LVL_4
```

The problem here is that customer's area (AREA_ID) does not allways point to the lowest fourth level of areas. Sometimes it points to fourth level AREA_ID, sometimes third and so on.

Depending of area levels, the resulting table should look like:

```
CUSTOMER_NAME | AREA_LVL_1 | AREA_LVL_2 | AREA_LVL_3 | AREA_LVL_4
==============+============+============+============+===========
John          | A          | A1         | A13        | A136
Maria         | B          | B2         | <null>     | <null>
Steve         | A          | A2         | A24        | <null>
```

I don't know how to make this recursion with variable number of levels inside single SQL query.
I need just single SQL query (not procedure with cursor passing the recursion loop).

Comment: Hi, can you provide the scripts for create table, insert scripts and the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a recursive `CTE` that returns all the levels for each area which will be joined to `customers`:

```
with 
  cte as (
    select id, area_name, parent_id, id start, 1 level from areas
    union all
    select a.id, a.area_name, a.parent_id, c.start, c.level + 1 
    from areas a inner join cte c
    on c.parent_id = a.id
    where c.parent_id is not null
  ),
  levels as (
    select id, area_name, parent_id, start, 
      max(level) over (partition by start) - level + 1 level 
    from cte
  )
select c.customer_name,
  max(case when l.level = 1 then l.area_name end) area_lvl_1,
  max(case when l.level = 2 then l.area_name end) area_lvl_2,
  max(case when l.level = 3 then l.area_name end) area_lvl_3,
  max(case when l.level = 4 then l.area_name end) area_lvl_4
from customers c left join levels l 
on l.start = c.area_id 
group by c.id, c.customer_name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=51f5f7d49eeee6cbcbabcbfb371080b3).
Results:

```
> customer_name | area_lvl_1 | area_lvl_2 | area_lvl_3 | area_lvl_4
> :------------ | :--------- | :--------- | :--------- | :---------
> John          | A          | A1         | A13        | A136      
> Maria         | B          | B2         | null       | null      
> Steve         | A          | A2         | A24        | null
```

Comment: The first area should be the highest level area, not the lowest level. Imagine that you have hierarchy like country-state-city-settlement, customer's AREA_ID sometimes ponts to city, sometimes to state, etc. First column must be the country, then state etc. If coustomer's AREA_ID points to city, one cannot put city in first column country.

Comment: It woks but I'm still studying it. This is excelent direction. I don't understand START part in CTE. But I can't help but get the impression that this query can be written more simply. Groupping of customer table makes me some difficulties because I have to join a lot of tables to it.

Answer (score 0):

One simpler solution:

```
select customer_name,

  case when a3.id is null then a4.area_name
       when a2.id is null then a3.area_name
       when a1.id is null then a2.area_name
       else a1.area_name
  end as area_name_lvl1,

  case when a3.id is null then null
       when a2.id is null then a4.area_name
       when a1.id is null then a3.area_name
       else a2.area_name
  end as area_name_lvl2,

  case when a2.id is null then null
       when a1.id is null then a4.area_name
       else a3.area_name
  end as area_name_lvl3,

  case when a1.id is null then null
       else a4.area_name
  end as area_name_lvl4

from customers c
left join areas a4 on a4.id=c.area_id
left join areas a3 on a3.id=a4.parent_id
left join areas a2 on a2.id=a3.parent_id
left join areas a1 on a1.id=a2.parent_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e8f5b0586cf3e08341b466c3f649533e).